# How to set Rules Cache Size

Tags: caching

According to the cachetuner, I should extend my "rules" cache. (By default it is 800KB)

Does anybody now which setting in sitecore config I should adapt in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting is called `Rules.MaxCachedRules`. The value should be in KB or MB. You can set it to 0 to disable the cache completely.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <!-- Default value if not set otherwise (800KB) -->
      <setting name="Rules.MaxCachedRules" value="2MB" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to disable Rule cache other than setting value to 0. This doesn't seem to work in Sitecore 9.1.1